# estimate for a function in the H^s space

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Consiser $f \in H^s(R^n)$ $(s> n/2)$. Show that :

$$ |f(x) - f(y)| \leq \gamma_s(|x-y|) || f||_s ,  \  \ \forall x,y \in R^n .$$

Where $\gamma_s(|x-y|) = 2 (2 \pi)^{\frac{-n}{2}}[\displaystyle\int_{R^n} (1 + |\theta|^2) \sin^2 \displaystyle\frac{(x-y) . \theta}{2} \ d \theta] .$

I dont have idea how to prove that . Someone can give me a hint ?

I know a know something near in relation with  my question and maybe helps:

for $f \in H^s(R^n)$ $(s> n/2)$  exists $\alpha \in (0,1)$ such that

$$| f(x+h) - f(x)| \leq 2^{1 - \alpha}|h|^{\alpha} (2 \pi)^{\frac{-n}{2}}[\displaystyle\int_{R^n} (1 + |\theta|^2)^{-(s - \alpha)} \ d \theta]$$

Thanks in advance

Comment: The last inequality does no make sense. There is no $x$ and $h$ in the right hand side.

Comment: @Tomás I did a error in the typing. now the error is fixed. thanks for your observation (my english is terrible sorry)